# size mismatch for classifier.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([9, 768]) from checkpoint. Current model is torch.Size([2, 768])

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")

model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")

---

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")
----> 2 model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")

E:\python\install\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_auto.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
1117         for config_class, model_class in MODEL_FOR_TOKEN_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING.items():
1118             if isinstance(config, config_class):
-> 1119                 return model_class.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, config=config, **kwargs)
1120
1121         raise ValueError(

E:\python\install\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
553                 raise RuntimeError(
554                     "Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}".format(
--> 555                         model.**class**.**name**, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)
556                     )
557                 )

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BertForTokenClassification:
size mismatch for classifier.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([9, 768]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([2, 768]).
size mismatch for classifier.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([9]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([2]).